# formulario dinámico con javaScript en angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validación

tengo una duda, se puede agregar al input un [fromControl] desde java script ? estoy haciendo un formulario, cada vez que se presiona un botón se crea un input, pero necesito validar esa entrada y ademas poder cambiar el nombre de la clase con [class.is-invalid].

lo que tengo es lo siguiente :

```
var consultorio = document.getElementById('cs');

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.className = 'form-control';
input.id = 'input-nombre-'+this.consultorio;

consultorio.appendChild(input);
```

y en html se mira de la siguiente manera :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-nombre-1" />
```

lo que busco es que el input se vea de la siguiente manera

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-nombre-1" [formControl]="nombre" [class.is-invalid]="(nombre.touched && nombre.hasError('required'))" />
```

Comment: lo puedes hacer directamente en el html

Comment: no por que, cada vez que se oprime un botón se crea dinamicamente un nuevo input, es por eso que no se puede hacerlo directamente.

Comment: crea una función para que sea disparada de tu elemento 'cs' por ejemplo:
<button id="cs" (click)="generaInput()">Generar</button>

Comment: si ya lo tengo el boton, ahora lo que me ocupa es crear in input con estas caracteristicas,  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-nombre-1" [formControl]="nombre" [class.is-invalid]="(nombre.touched && nombre.hasError('required'))" />, desde el ts.